# biicode "ERROR: Unable to properly clean project DB:" or "ERROR: Unexpected Exception database is locked"

Tags: biicode

I was playing with biicode, but I am facing this issue. I don't exactly know how I obtained that (I probably called the bii cpp:build command several time in parallel), but I want to fix my project :

```
bii cpp:build
INFO: Processing changes...
ERROR: Unexpected Exception
 database is locked
ERROR: Error executing command.
    Check the documentation in http://docs.biicode.com
    or ask in the forum http://forum.biicode.com
```

and when I try to clean stuffs I am obtaining that :

```
bii clean
ERROR: Unable to properly clean project DB:
database is locked
```

The project is really simple, nothing really tricky so I think it's not relevant to explain it.
I did not find any relevant information on the doc neither in the forum. I did not find any process still building it (my ide, nor my terminal)
Any idea to get it works ?

Many thanks for your answers !

PS : whouhou a [biicode](/questions/tagged/biicode) is now available :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not the cache "bii.db" database located in .biicode, but your project one, which is located in:

```
yourproject/bii/.hive.db
```

You can safely delete it. After that, inside your project folder, do a init again:

```
 yourproject$ bii init
```

That will restore a clean database. I suggest running a clean build:

```
$ bii clean
$ bii cpp:build
```

Those databases are only caches to store temporary information. All the information required is in your block files: biicode.conf, CMakeLists.txt, so deleting those caches is not dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite database seems to be locked, try rebooting computer. 
If it doesn't work try to remove database file manually.

The file is in your home directory in the folder *.biicode* and its named *bii.db*
If you are using linux/osx its on *~/.biicode/bii.bd*

Hope it works!

Comment: The problem is not the biicode cache, as "bii clean" does not try to clean the cache. The problem is the project cache.